# How convert string array with hexadecimal values to array of digit numbers in Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have the array:

```
array_h = "'0x5a','0x20','0x29','0x1','0x1','0x59eb5e8e'"
```

I need to convert it to this:

```
array_i = [41, 15 ,41, 1, 1, 1508444575]
```

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: link another question them, pls

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 0):

iteratively convert each hexstring to integer:

array_i = []

```
for eachHexString in array_h:
    array_i.append(int(eachHexString, 16))
```

Comment: i try and the out : invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'x'

Comment: i resolve with split first in the array str for remove ',' and after this work it
before : array_t = array_h.split(',')